# How to add top and bottom border to pdf using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

I have created a certificate pdf in php using wkhtmltopdf in landscape mode, everything else is working fine but I need to add thick green coloured borders to the top and bottom of the pdf. If I add the borders in the html then they appear much below from the top and much above from the bottom.

[image]

I have used the below code,

```
$cmd = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf -O landscape --margin-top 20  ".escapeshellarg($url)." ".escapeshellarg($file_name.".pdf");
            exec($cmd);
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this without some type of code :|

Comment: I have added an image and some code, can you please check now.